# Why i am getting 'Entity Not Found' error in symfony

Tags: symfony

I am writing web services, which is working fine on the localhost, but when uploaded on the server i am getting this error:

> {
>     "code": 500,
>     "message": "Entity was not found."
>   }

All entities are there, but still i am getting this error
This is my controller function:

```
public function getSendEmailBusinessAction($bussId, $userId)
{

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $query1 = $em->createQuery('SELECT list.email from StreetBumbApiBundle:BussOwner list WHERE list.id = :bussId')
        ->setParameter("bussId", $bussId);
    $list2 = $query1->getResult();
    $email = $list2[0]['email'];

    $query = $em->createQuery('SELECT list from StreetBumbApiBundle:UserOffers list WHERE list.userId = :userId')
        ->setParameter("userId", $userId);
    $list = $query->getResult();

   $userEmail =  $list[0]->getUserId()->getUsername();
   $offerDescription = $list[0]->getOfferId()->getDescription();
   $offerDate = $list[0]->getOfferId()->getExpiryDate();
   $offerPhno = $list[0]->getOfferId()->getPhno();

    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject('User and offer details selected by user')
        ->setFrom('admin@mail.com')
        ->setTo($email)
        ->setBody(
            "User Email Id: $userEmail",
            "Offer Description:  $offerDescription",
            "Offer Date and Time:  $offerDate",
            "Phone number:  $offerPhno"
        )

    ;
    $this->get('mailer')->send($message);

    if ($list == 0) {
        $view = View::create();
        $response[]=array("code"=>200,"message"=>"Data Not Found","data"=>"");
        $view->setData($response)->setStatusCode(200);
        return $view;
    }
    $response[]=array("code"=>200,"message"=>"Success","data"=>$list);
    $view = View::create();
    $view->setData($response)->setStatusCode(200);
    return $view;

}
```

Can anyone tell me where is problem?

Comment: does db has some values ?

Comment: Is the bundle containing the entity properly registered in the prod environment? Also try clearing the cache.

Comment: @GentiSaliu: there is no issue in the entity its registered properly, i did the cache clearing also. But now what happening is it is working with one id and not with another why it so?

Comment: pls show your full stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this error 'Entity Not Found' is the common one.

Answer is: You are trying to `get` some row which isn't there or deleted in referenced table.

Check if:

`getUserId() & getOfferId()` are returned in above code and the respective entries are in user and offer tables

You can try this also. If I am right this should work:

```
if ($list[0]->getUserId()) {
    $userEmail =  $list[0]->getUserId()->getUsername();
}
if ($list[0]->getOfferId()) {
    $offerDescription = $list[0]->getOfferId()->getDescription();
    $offerDate = $list[0]->getOfferId()->getExpiryDate();
    $offerPhno = $list[0]->getOfferId()->getPhno();
}
```